# In gwt read value from dynamic created text area

Tags: gwt

In gwt, I am creating a dynamic text area and now I want to read the value of the text area.

Can some help in me reading the value of dynamic created text area.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which classes you use. The convenient way to read from `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label` is to call `getText()`. But of cause the most generic way to get the interior of your "text area" is to call `getElement().getInnerHTML()` of your `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject` object. For example:

```
FlowPanel myTextArea = new FlowPanel();  // FlowPanel extends Widget extends UIObject
myTextArea.add(someWidget);
GWT.log("Here is what I have inside myTextArea: " +
    myTextArea.getElement().getInnerHTML());
```

A note of criticism. Normally, when you ask a question related to some custom UI, it should come along with at least few lines of code.